# Sending data from a component to a slice and receiving one parameter as undefined even though in the component it is being sent just fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to redux toolkit. I have a login component from where I am sending an email and password to user slice. From there I am making a post request via axios. The problem is I am receiving the email but the password is undefined. even though when I console log it in the component I can see that the password is correct. I have added another console log in the loginUser function in userSlice where I can see that email is fine but password is undefined. I have my own backend so since the password is undefined it returns an error.

Please help.

[image]

[image]

I tried debugging but couldn't understand the problem. please help!!!

Comment: I believe changing the " userPassword " in second image to " password " will solve your problem.

Comment: It was password before, I changed it to user password to test but unfortunately didn’t eorked out

Comment: You shouldn’t take pictures of your code. Post it as text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you give wrong variable name on thunk, please do:

```
createAsyncThunk('user/loginUser', async ({password, email})
```

Hope this answer your problem.

Also it's better to copy/paste your code here in question instead of sending an screen shot.

Comment: I don’t think so that type can be a problem here because the email is being read correctly just the password is undefined